# Running python files from command prompt

Tags: python, mechanize

I have written a python program in eclipse that imports the mechanize module. It works perfectly there. When I run the .py file from the command prompt, it shows this error: "No module named mechanize". How do I rectify this?

Comment: what's your dir structure looks like? where did you run your command?

Comment: this is the file i'm trying to run: C:\EclipseWorkspace\csse120\proj\src\pone.py .I have included the meachanize module in site-packages.

Comment: trying printing the value of `sys.path` (`import sys` first) in each case... there'll be a difference.

Comment: @zhangxaochen: I ran it here: C:\EclipseWorkspace\csse120\proj\src

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that Eclipse and prompt are using the same python version. Simply typing $ python on the command line show you the version you are using from there.

The mechanize module must be in your site-packages folder in order for python to find it.

(C:\Python\Lib\site-packages)

If the module is not in your site-packages folder then you can install it as follows:

Download the source code from http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/m/mechanize/mechanize-0.2.5.tar.gz

Now extract and install the package (This is what you do on Linux, on Mac or Win. this might be slightly different)

$ tar zxvf mechanize-0.2.5.tar.gz)

$ sudo python setup.py install

Comment: Thanks. TIL you have to install a package to run from cmd, although its enough to include it in external libraries under project properties to run from eclipse.

Comment: Using external libraries from prompt is also possible, you can do this by setting the environment variable PYTHONPATH and putting your files in this directory. This is typically done during early development, before you write a  setup.py module for your package and use it to install your package into a Python installation.